# recursive function that computes the external path length of a regular binary tree

Tags: recursion, tree, binary, binary-tree

**how to write a recursive function that computes the external path length of a regular binary tree**?
We can assume that we have a Boolean function that tells whether a tree is a leaf and an integer function that returns the number of leaves of a binary tree.
I know that the external path length is the sum of the lengths of the paths from the root to all the leaves of the tree. Should the algorithm be like this?

```
int Recursive (Node root, int totalNodes) {
   if (totalNodes == 1)
          return 0;
   else if (totalNodes == 2)
          return 1; 
   else {
      int leftNodes = CountNodes(root.left);
      int RightNodes = CountNodes(root.right);
      return ( Recursive(root.left, leftNodes) 
                  + Recursive(root.right, RightNodes));
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice assignment. However, Stack Overflow is a question & answer site, and you have not posted a question. A question would include this challenge, but then also your attempt at solving it (preferably with some code), example input and the output that is expected for it, and what you get instead (an error, an infinite loop, a wrong output)... and the *question* that relates to your efforts.

Comment: Your update now has a question, but the other elements are missing. If there is no sign of effort on your side, why do you expect effort from our side?

Comment: what about now? Thank you for your comments btw ^^

Comment: Yes, that is an improvement!